# chessboard: How to set the chess pieces in the foreground?

Tags: chessboard

[image]

How can I set the chess piece in the foreground?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}

\begin{document}
\def\mymoves{a8-e4, e4-h7}
\chessboard[
pgfstyle=straightmove,
cornerarc=0pt, % no effect
pgfcornerarc=0pt, % no effect
backcornerarc=0pt, % no effect
arrow=, linewidth=0.2em, color=red, 
opacity=0.5, 
%addpgf=\pgfsetcornersarced,
%addpgf=\pgfsetroundcap,
markmove=\mymoves,
addpieces=bd5,
]
\end{document}
```

Comment: see 6.1 The pgf-pictures in the documentation.

Comment: Aha, so I have to say `backmove={....}` instead of `markmove={....}`

Comment: No, it's NOT that simple. I accidentally used a black figure here. The white figure is apparently not filled. And then it doesn't work again. Then this is again a fundamental problem of the package. Can you give me a complete working MWE? Or do I have to completely hack 3 chess packages that work side by side and work against the user?